# If ratio of two sides of triangle is constant then find radius of circle

Tags: circles, triangles

The base of triangle $ABC$ is $AB=6$ and the third vertex $C$ moves such that $\frac{sinA}{sinB}=2$. Then locus of vertex of $C$ is a circle then find the radius of circle.

Using sine rule we get $\frac{BC}{AC}=2$ but how to proceed further to get equation of cirlce?

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Hint: the locus of $C$ is an [Apollonian circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius#Apollonius.27_definition_of_a_circle) which has as diameter the segment between the two points which divide $BA$ in ratio $2:1$ internally and externally, respectively.

Comment: If you let A=(0,0), B=(6,0), and C=(x,y), then you can easily find three points for C on your circle: (1) point (2,0) where BC=4 and AC=2, (2) point (-2,0) where BC=8 and AC=4, and (3) (0,sqrt(12)) which can be obtained using right triangle.  Using these three points you can solve for h, k and r  [h=0, k=sqrt(12)/3, r^2 = 16/3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use coordinates . . .

$$\text{Let}\;A = (-3,0),\;\;B = (3,0),\;\;C=(x,y)$$

Then

\begin{align*}
&\frac{\sin A}{\sin B}=2\\[8pt]
\iff\;&\frac{BC}{AC}=2\\[8pt]
\iff\;&\frac{BC^2}{AC^2}=4\\[8pt]
\iff\;&\frac{(x-3)^2+y^2}{(x+3)^2 + y^2}=4\\[8pt]
\end{align*}

Now simply cross-multiply, and express the resulting equation in the form
$$(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = r^2$$

Can you finish it?

Comment: Good explanation. But you should proceed by equivalence, i.e., use $\iff$ symbols instead of $\implies$

Comment: Sure, thanks -- will edit.